# How to perform map matching algo using lidar scan s

Tags: localization, lidar, mapping

I have run a code to extract features from lidar scans like poles and facades, and I created the reference map just concatenating results from each scan (i.e local map) now my question is;
How can I run map matching algo to get the robots poses?

Comment: Just to mention I'm working with python and I will appreciate if you recommend some references related on that

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation will work only if your positioning/localization is super precise which is seldom the case. What you want to be doing is [scan registration](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration_api.html). ICP and NDT are the two most widely used registration techniques which you can speed up by matching only the features you are extracting. In scan registration, your sensor gets a scan (from which you will extract features) and match them to the next scan which will give you a pose between them. So if you know your starting pose, you can get your new pose!

Of course you will find a lot of resources using C/C++, but PCL has a [python version of icp](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl/tree/master/examples/official/Registration) which I haven't used. So if you do end up using it, please let us know!

Finally, if you are working within ROS, there are several packages/projects that can perform SLAM for you like [rtabmap](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/), [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping), etc.

Comment: thanks a lot you feed me, but what is the difference between scan registration and map matching

Comment: scan registration is one (and the most widely used) technique to achieve map matching. Map matching is a generic term

Comment: oh, now it's clear for me, scan registration is a method from the concept of map matching